# What is the correct way to use Regex_replace to replace a '|' with a '-' in Spark Java's column named details?

Tags: java, string, apache-spark, regexp-replace, spark-java

I have a column named details which has special character as `|` I want to replace it with `-` . How can I do it in spark Java?

I have tried:

1. `regex_replace(details ,"|","-")`
2. `regex_replace(details ,"\\|","-")`

Just wanted to know which is correct one or two and what is the use of `\\` before the special character. What if I don't include `\\`, will my `|` be replaced in the `details` string?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include `\\`, which is an escape sequence for the regular expression, you will get a `-` in between every single character of your string. Meaning that if you have:

`my | text`, and you use `regexp_replace(details, "|", "-")`, you will end up with: `-m-y- -|- -t-e-x-t-` because `|` has a special meaning in regular expression (`a|b` -> alternamte - match either `a` or `b`).

Therefore, you must use your second option which will return `my - text`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider.

With many coding languages, a string literal may include what are called *[escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)*.
Essentially, it is a syntax used to represent a *[non-printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_code_chart)* character, such as the new-line character.

Consider the following *string* value.

```
string = "stack\noverflow"
```

The reverse-solidus here is a signifier, called an *[escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)*, which is used to render the character that immediately follows it as a qualifier—as opposed to, in this case, a literal *n*.
In this case, *\n* is mapped to the *[line-feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)* character, commonly referred to as a "newline" character.

If you evaluated *string* by printing it to the standard-out, it would result in the following.

```
stack
overflow
```

In your aggregate method, *regex_replace*, the first parameter is a *[regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern*.
Regular expressions are just a set of syntactic values, used to represent a literal value.
For example, the expression *[a-z]* will match any lower-case letter, *a* through *z*.
So, in regex, you can type *"[a-z]at"*, and it will match *"bat", "cat", "mat", "vat"*, etc.

In regular expression patterns, the *[| character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended)* is a syntactic character, similar to the *||*, or-operator, used in most coding languages.

If you want to represent a literal *|* character in a regular expression pattern, you must *un-escape* it, using the \, reverse-solidus, escape-character.

So, essentially your first parameter is evaluating to an escaped regular expression meta-character, which then needs to be escaped within the string literal.

So you arrive at 2 reverse-solidi.

In regard to what happens if you do not include the double reverse-solidi.

Regular expression pattern matching occurs in a left-to-right traversal of the valued string.

What will happen is it will match your first character, or nothing—redunant—and place the replacement value, in this case a *-*.

It will continue to the next character, and since it, again, matches, will place another replacement value.
This will continue until the end of the string is reached.

So, if your *string* value is "stack\noverflow", you would get the following replacement string.

```
-s-t-a-c-k-\n-o-v-e-r-f-l-o-w-
```